# Average Discounted Payoffs in Continuous Time

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory

While reading some theory papers that model a continuous time problem, I have noticed the way they represent the expression for average discounted payoff is of this form, where $r> 0 $ is the discount rate,$$r\int_0^\infty e^{-rs}u\left(x_s\right)ds$$ Can someone explain to me where does the $r$ in this expression come from? I understand the use of $e^{-rs}$ since it is the discount factor, but can't understand why we also multiply by $r$

For example see this paper https://elischolar.library.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3011&context=cowles-discussion-paper-series#page=12. On page 10 (PDF page 12).

Comment: I changed a few typos (at least I think they were) in your main formula. Feel free to revert back if you think I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $r$, or rather $\frac{1}{1/r}$, is the "average" part of the average discounted payoff. As you note, $\mathrm e^{-rs}$ is the discount factor. Observe that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{rs}\,\mathrm ds = \frac1r.
\end{equation}
If the payoff is $p$ in every instant of time, the discounted payoff (with no averaging) is $p/r$. But if we want to get $p$ as the *average* discounted payoff, we would weight the discount factor by $\frac{1}{1/r}$ so that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm e^{rs}}{1/r}p\,\mathrm ds = r\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{rs}p\,\mathrm ds = p.
\end{equation}

In the paper you referred to, the average discounted payoff on page 10 comes from:
\begin{equation}
\int_t^\infty (1)\frac{\mathrm e^{-rs}}{1/r}\,\mathrm ds - \int_0^t \frac{\mathrm e^{-rs}}{1/r} c_i(u_{i,s})\,\mathrm ds
\end{equation}
where the discount factor is weighted by $\frac{1}{1/r}$.

Comment: Thankyou very much!